# Clerk.dev Unhandled Runtime Error, TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: authentication, next.js, cors, t3, clerk

I am following the official T3 stack tutorial.

I am stuck at clerk authentication. I modified my _app.tsx to the following:

```
import { type AppType } from "next/app";

import { api } from "~/utils/api";

import "~/styles/globals.css";
import {ClerkProvider, SignedIn, SignedOut, SignIn} from "@clerk/nextjs";

const MyApp: AppType = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
      <ClerkProvider {...pageProps}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ClerkProvider>
  );
};

export default api.withTRPC(MyApp);
```

And when I visit my home page: http://127.0.0.1:3000/ or http://localhost:3000/ I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3hka.png)

Checking the browser console the main (and first) error I see is the following:

Screenshot of the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O8af.png)

Which is a basic CORS block that I can do nothing about client side, it seems.

What am I missing? I am banging my head with this problem for days now and found nothing like this with Google.

This seems to cause clerk not to work at all.

Versions I use for context:

- "@clerk/nextjs": "^4.15.0",
- "next": "^13.2.4",
- "@types/node": "^18.15.5",
- "typescript": "^5.0.2"

I tried the following so far:

- Googling the problem, like "clerk failed to fetch", "clerk auth failed to fetch", "clerk auth CORS error", "IsomorphicClerk.loadClerkJS error", I added reddit at the end of the searches as well but I have found nobody experiencing this error
- I purged the project and started over to see if I messed up something in the process but the same happened
- importing ClerkProvider from a different library (@clerk/react - I think)
- Checking clerk dashboard if I can set CORS exceptions, but found nothing, maybe except for the production

Comment: Sorry for the nooby image links, I also had to delete the errors because it contained links to clerk and I could not post it as it was flagged as spam. But everything is on the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue with my exact problem in another repo (t3-turbo-and-clerk):

https://github.com/clerkinc/t3-turbo-and-clerk/issues/39

The issue was caused by my HTTPSEverywhere issue. Disabling it on localhost solved my issue.

Leaving it here for other people to find.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with the same project, but I didn't have the HTTPS Everywhere extension. I was able to resolve this by clicking the fetch link in the console to bypass the app and go straight to the Clerk provided log in page and logged back in.

Comment: In the meantime I had a similar issue, I will leave it here for others: it had very similar symptoms as written above. Clearing local cookies solved it. I never had problems like this on production though.